# redirect to login page only from one particular page

Tags: wordpress

Need to re-direct the user to the WordPress login page when user visit one particular page.
by default the site doesn't require login, anyone can view the content of the site.

Home page: http://www.sivaniskitchen.com

Login required on this page: http://www.sivaniskitchen.com/submit-a-recipe/

When user visits any other pages/links except the one page mentioned above , no Login is required.

not able to understand the instructions found online

i am not a programmer/web designer, i need step by steps instructions to resolve my request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code in your Activate theme's functions.php file.

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {

    if ( is_page( 2 ) && !is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 3 ) );
        die;
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

In this in place of '2' you need to add your 'submit-a-recipe' (page name/id/slug any of one) and in place of '3' your login page id/name/slug.

Comment: thank you for the reply, surely will try this and update you the result. One more question, if the user is already logged in and visited the 2 page again, it should not redirect to the login page.. please clarify

Comment: Ohk. update you for if user is login then not redirect in short time.

Comment: I do update in the code. so using this if user not login then only page is redirect.

Comment: I tried what you said but no success, I have posted below all my changes for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Theme Function.php file

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {

    if ( is_page( 'submit-a-recipe' ) && !is_user_logged_in() ) 
    {
        wp_redirect('www.sivaniskitchen.com/login');
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

I have created a new page in my wordpress page title Login;

> http://www.sivaniskitchen.com/login/

now, when a non-logged in user visits the page

> http://www.sivaniskitchen.com/submit-a-recipe/

the webpage is redirecting to

> http://www.sivaniskitchen.com/submit-a-recipe/wp-login.php
>   which is an invalid/404 url. please see this

Comment: wp_redirect('login');

Do change like this in place of wp_redirect('www.sivaniskitchen.com/login');